# Delete files and subfolders with files in folder

Tags: python

i am using following code to delete all files in one folder that consist of zip file I will not to be deleted and one txt file and one subfolder that consist of lot of txt files and two subfolders with files:

```
for file_object in os.listdir(folder_path):
    file_object_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_object)
    print file_object_path
    if os.path.isfile(file_object_path):
        if 'zip.zip' in file_object:
            pass
        else:
            print ('       Deleting file ' + file_object)
            os.unlink(file_object_path)
    else:
        print ('       Deleting folder ' + file_object)
        rmtree(file_object_path)
```

But result is Error 5 Access denied to delete subfolder. Other files in main folder has not been deleted because first file to be checked was actually subfolder with access denied. I hope someone understand description of problem I have :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[python-shutil-rmtree-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656322/python-shutil-rmtree-fails-on-windows-with-access-is-denied). I missed to notice you already use rmtree.