# shutil.rmtree doesn't delete all files and folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, shutil

I want do delete a directory with python. I used this:

```py
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('path/to/dir', ignore_errors=True)
```

but when I go into the folder, there is still a folder.
(Its a .git folder which has content)

How can I also delete this directory too?

> I already searched and tested many other posts but all didn't work like it should.

Comment: What does happens if you do `shutil.rmtree('path/to/dir', ignore_errors=False)`?

Comment: If you set ignore errors to false, what errors pop up? There might be some info on what is going wrong

Comment: @Daweo It gives a permission error on a file

Comment: @NicholasKrebs this mean you attempt to remove file which you are not allowed to remove

Comment: @Pietro `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert: 'path/to/folder\\.git\\objects\\pack\\pack-f29a84ca6bef2ed3fa9e877d283bd0bf3075519a.idx'` its german it means Access denied

Comment: @Daweo then theres no way to delete it?

Comment: @NicholasKrebs yes, unless you are able to somewhat grant right to do so.

Comment: @Daweo yes I think I can. Then how I do it with python?

Comment: @NicholasKrebs then change permissions in files that remained, so they can be removed and then `shutil.rmtree` should work as required

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2656405/2237151) there is a suggested approach, but I cannot test it (my Windows installation broke and I never bothered to reinstall it :D).