# shutil.rmtree to remove readonly files

Tags: python, shutil

I want to use `shutil.rmtree` in Python to remove a directory. The directory in question contains a `.git` control directory, which git marks as read-only and hidden.

The read-only flag causes `rmtree` to fail. In Powershell, I would do "del -force" to force removal of the read-only flag. Is there an equivalent in Python? I'd really rather not walk the whole tree twice, but the `onerror` argument to rmtree doesn't seem to retry the operation, so I can't use

```
def set_rw(operation, name, exc):
    os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)

shutil.rmtree('path', onerror=set_rw)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the file in the `onerror` callback?

Comment: It is strange that .git is read-only

Comment: I'd have to do a full (recursive) rmtree in the onerror, as it's the .git subdirectory that's readonly, but that might work. And 'git is made hidden and readonly presumably to simulate the Unix behaviour of not displaying dotfiles. I think the behaviour is horrible (hg doesn't do this) but I have to live with it :-(

Comment: You could change the permissions on the files first, then go through and edit them, I can post a solution for this if you'd like

Comment: @wnnmaw would that not mean a double-walk of the tree, using os.walk to get everything and force RW mode? If that's what you mean, I know how to do that (as I said, I just want to avoid it if I can). But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You don't have to walk it twice, just as you walk change the permission, then remove the file.  Additionally, I'm not sure what system your on, but if its Windows the permissions are inherited, so you should be able to change the top level and have it cascade down if they're set up right

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889686

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After more investigation, the following appears to work:

```
def del_rw(action, name, exc):
    os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
    os.remove(name)

shutil.rmtree(path, onerror=del_rw)
```

In other words, actually remove the file in the onerror function. (You might need to check for a directory in the onerror handler and use rmdir in that case - I didn't need that but it may just be something specific about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

shutil.rmtree is used to delete directories that are not empty (remove tree).

```
    import os
    import stat
    import shutil
    def del_ro_dir(dir_name):
        '''Remove Read Only Directories'''
        for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(dir_name, topdown=True):
            os.chmod(root,
                # For user ...
                stat.S_IRUSR |
                stat.S_IWUSR |
                stat.S_IXUSR |
                # For group ...
                stat.S_IWGRP |
                stat.S_IRGRP |
                stat.S_IXGRP |
                # For other ...
                stat.S_IROTH |
                stat.S_IWOTH |
                stat.S_IXOTH
            )
        shutil.rmtree(dir_name)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        del_ro_dir('dir_name_here')
```

To delete a file only, you can use the following code:

```
    import os
    import stat
    def rmv_rof(file_name):
        '''Remov Read Only Files'''
        if os.path.exists(file_name):
            os.chmod(file_name, stat.S_IWRITE)
            os.remove(file_name)
        else:
            print('The file does not exist.')
    rmv_rof('file_name_here')
```

You can read detailed information here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#module-stat

https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#rmtree-example

Answer (score 0):

You could just go with the quick-and-dirty method and do `subprocess.check_call(["rm", "-rf", filename])`. Likely won't work on Windows though.

Comment: Consider adding `"--"` as a 3rd argument before `filename` -- that way the code will work correctly even with filenames that start with literal dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [`rmtree` example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#rmtree-example), copied straight from the `shutil` docs (probably added after the OP):

> ```py
> import os, stat
> import shutil
>
> def remove_readonly(func, path, _):
>    "Clear the readonly bit and reattempt the removal"
>    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
>    func(path)
>
> shutil.rmtree(directory, onexc=remove_readonly)
> ```

Note there's a minor difference w.r.t. the accepted answer: The example above uses the `func` argument, rather than explicitly calling `os.remove`.

Also note that `onerror` is deprecated as of python 3.12, to be replaced by `onexc`.