# how to `shutil.move` with readonly files across drives

Tags: python, windows, file-access, shutil

At least on windows, `shutil.move` a folder containing readonly files to another drive will fail.  It fails because `move` is implemented with a `copy` followed by a `rmtree`.  In the end, it's the `rmtree` trying to delete non writable files.

Currently I work around it by first setting the `stat.S_IWUSER` for all (nested) files, but now I should still restore the original `stat` afterwards:

```
def make_tree_writable(source_dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for name in files:
            make_writable(path.join(root, name))    

def make_writable(path_):
    os.chmod(path_, stat.S_IWUSR)

def movetree_workaround(source_dir, target_dir):
    make_tree_writable(source_dir)
    shutil.move(source_dir, target_dir)
```

So I wonder: is this the way?  Is there a `shutil2` in the making that I could use?  Can I be of any help there?

Comment: Why not do `shutil.copytree()` first, then change permissions of the source and finally `shutil.rmtree` on the source?

Comment: Why not pour that into an answer so that I can upvote it?

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [shutil.rmtree to remove readonly files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21261132/364696)

Comment: :) Okay, answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in two steps: first, use `shutil.copytree()` to copy the full directory and file structure with appropriate permissions. Then you can change permissions of the source to make sure you have rights to delete stuff, and use `shutil.rmtree()` to remove the old source.