# Delete a file from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I'm tying to delete a file using this code and I am getting "YES File is present" but on os.remove I am getting error.

Code

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/WhatsApp Documents/7K1')
    if os.path.exists("file.jpg"):
        print('YES File is Present')
        os.remove('file.jpg')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

Error

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'file.jpg'
```

Comment: The code looks fine (it has a tiny race condition, but itll probably always work). Windows isn't letting you do this for some reason. Does deleting the file by hand work?

Comment: Yes It allows me to delete it manually

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889597/deleting-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import os  
os.remove("ChangedFile.csv")
print("File Removed!")
```

Comment: My file is not on the root level. It is in this path C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/WhatsApp Documents/7K1

Comment: place this python code wherever your file is located and try running it.

Comment: this code wont run, as OP code is correct, it is just window permission error.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant and does actually address the OP’s issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the python program as administrator. Your code looks fine the issue is you dont have permission to delete the file.

If you are executing the program from command prompt launch it with run as administrator and run the programme

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: how are you running the python program is it from command prompt?

Comment: right click your application(if it is command prompt) and run as administrator

Comment: Yes. I am trying to delete it on through the terminal

Comment: can you make sure the file is not opened by any other application and then once again right click and run as administrator

Comment: The file is not opened by any application. and when I again run it I'm getting the same error