# Python shutil.rmtree: cannot remove git dir on win7

Tags: python, git, windows-7, directory

Simple test case with python 2.7 on windows 7 prof 64 bits:
via python I checkout a git project in a directory, let's say, `c:/temp/project`.
Afterwards I delete it with the python command

```
shutil.rmtree('c:/temp/project')
```

After the command, the folder is empty (no hidden files) but it cannot be removed it self because of the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\temp\\project'
```

I've checked and git is not running at that moment (I've even tried a sleep(10) to be sure).
I've tried this solution:

[What user do python scripts run as in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213706/what-user-do-python-scripts-run-as-in-windows/1214935#1214935)

but it doesn't work, same error.
Tried a `os.system('rmdir')` but same error.
Tried `win32api.SetFileAttributes()` function but same error.
If I delete the folder via explorer, there's no problem.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You are not executing this Python script from within the C:\\temp\\project folder, do you?

Comment: These things happen. I've added an answer, please tick! :)

Answer (score 3):

The OP was running in the wrong dir ... but i found this thread for a problem using GitPython; seems like a common case, as git-python will hold handles to your repo if you don't clean up in some odd ways:

```
import gc, stat

gc.collect()
your_repo_obj.git.clear_cache()

# now this will succeed: 
shutil.rmtree(your_repo_dir)
```

the need for these gymnastics are due to both a bug, and by design.  This bug describes the reasons:
https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/553

Answer (score 0):

You are probably executing the Python code inside the folder you are trying to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My solution:

```py
import stat, os, shutil
from pathlib import Path

def readonly_to_writable(foo, file, err):
  if Path(file).suffix in ['.idx', '.pack'] and 'PermissionError' == err[0].__name__:
    os.chmod(file, stat.S_IWRITE)
    foo(file)

shutil.rmtree('repo-catalog/', onerror=readonly_to_writable)
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Comment: @Destroy666 Oops. I was looking for a solution to the same problem, but did not follow the link in the topic. I would have solved my problem faster if I followed this link. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213706/what-user-do-python-scripts-run-as-in-windows/1214935#1214935) is better for my case (I didn't use a GitPython).