# When using python os.rmdir, get PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-permissions

I'm building a file-transfer script, and the source cleanup function makes use of `os.rmdir('C:\\Users\\Grav\\Desktop\\TestDir0\\Om')`. This is the error I get:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Grav\\Desktop\\TestDir0\\Om'
```

I checked the permissions on the folder `Om` through the Windows 7 and they are set to allow deletion for my user account. I've also tried setting my interpreter to run as admin. The problem persists and I'm stymied. Much obliged to anyone with insight!

Comment: Did you close your file in your code before trying to remove it?

Comment: In Windows you can't* access or delete a file that's being held open by some other process. Some call it a feature. *at least without doing some weird mangling with the win32 api

Comment: I didn't actually _open_ the file (also, it's a folder so I'm not sure if Python treats it as "open" or "closed" like a file object), but I did copy the tree that contained it using shutil.copytree. Perhaps the copy function leaves folder objects in an "open" state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution here: [What user do python scripts run as in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213706/what-user-do-python-scripts-run-as-in-windows)

It seems as if the offending folder has a stubborn read-only attribute. Adding in a handler to change such read-only flags worked like a charm for me.

All of you who posted suggestions, you helped me track down the final answer, so thank you!

Answer (score 18):

I had a same issue, could do it via `shutil` module.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/path/to/your/dir/')
```

Answer (score 13):

uncheck read-only attribute box found in the properties of the file/folder.
[image]

Comment: How do you do this programmatically though?

Answer (score 9):

Try deleting all files in the directory before deleting the directory:

```
import os
path_to_dir  = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\temp'  # path to directory you wish to remove
files_in_dir = os.listdir(path_to_dir)     # get list of files in the directory

for file in files_in_dir:                  # loop to delete each file in folder
    os.remove(f'{path_to_dir}/{file}')     # delete file

os.rmdir(path_to_dir)                      # delete folder
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if:

1. You are not in dir `0m` and running script from there.
2. You don't have any windows open that list the `0m` dir.
3. Since `0m` is a subdirectory of `TestDir0`, you have correct permissions for `TestDir0`

Comment: Certainly. I'm not running from `Om`, I don't have any windows open except the interpreter and the .py file itself in Notepad++, and I have permissions for `TestDir0`.