# How to delete directory containing .git in python

Tags: python, git

I am not able to override/delete the folder containing .git in python. I am working on the below configuration:

- OS - Windows 8
- Python - 3.5.2
- Git - 2.9.2

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your intent with that? Please provide your code, that is not working.

Comment: path='D:/code/taget/partnerrelationshipmanagement_V2/'

def handleRemoveReadonly(func, path, exc):
  excvalue = exc[1]
  if func in (os.rmdir, os.remove) and excvalue.errno == errno.EACCES:
      os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRWXU| stat.S_IRWXG| stat.S_IRWXO) # 0777
      func(path)
  else:
      raise
shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True, onerror=handleRemoveReadonly)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39266408/edit) your question to add the code formatted. And please add the "python" tag to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove git repository, in python, on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878089/how-to-remove-git-repository-in-python-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using shutil to remove a directory that's not empty. If `os.rmdir` is used on a directory that's not empty an exception is raised.

```
import shutil

shutil.rmtree('/.git')
```

Comment: whenever to delete directory containing .git will raise PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:

Comment: Ok, this problem is raised in windows. Try seeing this StackOverflow Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213706/what-user-do-python-scripts-run-as-in-windows

Comment: Above link also does not tell about to delete folder which is having .git

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/path/to/your/dir/')
```

Comment: it does not work out for folder which is having .git inside.

Comment: you should check permissions, it could be that you have no permission for .git directory and it has no relation to python. Either change permissions to .git directory or run script as root, in that case

Answer (score -1):

try this,
It will work

```
os.system('rmdir /S /Q "{}"'.format(baseDirectory))
```